# How to resolve Access-Control-Allow-Origin error with Azure AD

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I am getting an error when I try to make request from my react SPA application to get id and access token from Azure AD. Below is the error from the browser console log:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am trying PKCE flow for my SPA and I am not using any JS library. I am making hte request with plain XMLHttpRequest.

Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this error with install "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or same extention on your browser.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it. Are you talking about doing some configuration or adding an extension to the browser?

Comment: Adding an extention to the browser
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Comment: This extension was blocked by my system. Is there any other way we can handle it like configuring CORS in Azure AD??